# jQuery children() values?

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I am trying to get my JavaScript to generate a select HTML input element on a webpage. The problem with this is it is not getting the values of the children from that node and is causing `ObjectUnknownHTMLElement` when generating my select box.

**XML**

```
<Salutation restricted="no" type="dropdownBox" tooltip="Select a title for the customer" required="yes" size="6">
    <value>Mr</value>
    <value>Sir</value>
    <value>Mrs</value>
    <value>Miss</value>
    <value>Lord</value>
</Salutation>
```

**jQuery code**

```
//hack to pretend its html by wrapping divs to make jquery find work on IE7
selection = $("<div>" + xml + "</div>").find("Salutation").children();
//generate a select box
var selectBox = "<select id=\"Salutation\"> ";
for ( var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++)
{
    selectBox += "<option value=\"" + selection[j].v + "\">" + selection[j]
        + "</option>";
}
```

**Output HTML**

```
<select id="salutation">
    <option value="undefined">[object HTMLUnknownElement]</option>
    <option value="undefined">[object HTMLUnknownElement]</option>
    <option value="undefined">[object HTMLUnknownElement]</option>
    <option value="undefined">[object HTMLUnknownElement]</option>
    <option value="undefined">[object HTMLUnknownElement]</option>
</select>
```

I guess my use of the children method in jQuery does not work at getting the values from the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to wrap the XML in a `<div>`. Just jQuery it:

```
selection = $(xml).find("Salutation").children();
```

Then, since `<Salutation>` is the root node of the XML, don't try to `.find()` it:

```
selection = $(xml).children();
```

Now you've got to use [actual jQuery API methods](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text out of each XML element:

```
$selection = $(xml).children();
var selectBox = '<select id="Salutation">';
$selection.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    selectBox += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
});
selectBox += '</select>'
```

I don't know what makes you think these elements have `v` attributes such that `selection[j].v` would ever work.

There are still nicer ways to build up a tree of elements:

```
var $selection = $(xml).children();
var $selectBox = $('<select/>', {id: 'Salutation'});
$selectBox.append(
    $selection.map(function() {
        return $('<option/>', { text: $(this).text() });
    }).get()
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/RbEs9

---

All that aside, this *really* seems like a task better suited to [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) than JavaScript.

Comment: the div is a hack when using AJAX and Jquery in IE7 , otherwise you cannot parse the XML. See here

Comment: Salutation is not the root, I have another level called "<templateFields>"

Comment: Okay, then `.find('Salutation')` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the innerHTML of your selection: http://jsfiddle.net/Kmp7v/

```
var selectBox = "<select id=\"Salutation\"> ";
            for ( var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++)
            {
                selectBox += "<option value=\"" + selection[j].innerHTML + "\">" + selection[j].innerHTML
                        + "</option>";
            }
```